# Type of transformation needed for Clustering in SAS E-Miner

Tags: clustering, sas

I'm performing a cluster analysis with a dateset that contain over 100 varibles (after imputing, replacing and eliminating correlated vars ..)

Before hiting the clustering, for the transformation node, should I tranform all variables with LOG10 or do the standarsization ?

For continuous vars that can be regrouped in interval (revenue for exemple), do I need to transfer it with the Bucket option ?

OR I have to see every variable (after been cutted to 99% percentile to eliminate outliers) if it's skewed then apply the log10, and for the rest, apply the z-score ?

OR

Even do not transform any variable if I'm going to use the Minkowski distance in K-means ?

Answer (score 1):

Study each variable separately.

With so many variables, it does not seem very likely that they can all be scaled alike.